# Running test in virtual machine

Tags: selenium, grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkiY3.png)
what is problem.
i wanna run remote test on virtual machine and ip of vm is a node of hub but i can not access jar file in vm. install JRE and jdk and try java -jar selenium-server-stabdalone-3.3.1 in cmd but have error "unable to access jar file "
please help me,problem is in image, am beginner .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need simply add .jar extension

```
java -jar selenium-server-stabdalone-3.3.1.jar
```